# Found edit suggestion to a tag of an 5k+ user in the suggested-edits queue, how is it possible?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, privileges

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21076056) I found something interesting. @user1095108 (rep around 6700) suggested an edit to a tag wiki.

But @user1095108 is a 5k+ user, thus he should be able to edit the tag wiki instantly, without the approving process.

How is it possible?

<sub>Another surprising side-effect: although the tag wiki was created by himself, he still needs approval to change it. Although it is logical: tag wikis don't have an owner in the sense as the ordinary posts have.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

5K is when you can *review* tag wiki edits. Unrestricted editing doesn't come until 20K.